# How to exit shell mode in system()

Tags: php, linux

I have a php script which should use some preset system aliases. I.e. "alias ll=ls -l"

In terminal "ll" works but from php system("ll") outputs

```
sh: ll: command not found
```

How do I exit "sh" and execute my terminal commands?

P.S.: May be I missunderstood the basic linux components shell and bash. In this case, please correct me/the post

Comment: How are the aliases defined? Are they defined *in* the script? What language is the script? Is it not `sh`?

Comment: @kojiro I am guessing he wants to use aliases from `~/.bashrc`

Comment: The script is a php script. The aliases are defined globally in ".cshrc"

Comment: Maybe login to user shell using [ssh2_shell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-shell.php) ?

Comment: I mean "C Shell". The "system("whoami");" outputs my user name. I also assume that PHP script will be executed by my username.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) aren't clear about this, but presumably PHP's `system` is a reflection of [Standard C's `system(3)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html), which *hands the argument command to the command interpreter sh(1)*. If you want to avoid the shell, you'll need to use another feature of PHP besides `system` (like explicit fork/exec). That's context, but it won't help you solve your problem.

In your case it seems you just want the aliases in an rcfile. Scripts invoked by `system` calls aren't going to read your rcfile unless you take extraordinary steps to make that happen, and even if you do, it's going to be non-obvious to the maintenance programmer. I'd strongly advise you to put the alias in the script or command argument itself, or simply call the command explicitly (`ls -al`).

You can also manually source the rcfile from your script, or call `system(csh -i 'yourcommands')` to force `csh` to be invoked as an interactive shell (which should cause your rcfile to be read). I think this is a bad idea because it is effectively forcing the shell to behave inconsistently with its environment, but I'm including it here for completeness.

Most of the above I got from a quick read through the *Startup and shutdown* section of the csh manual on my Mac (Mavericks). There are other potential solutions there that I haven't laid out, as well.

Comment: @Caniko Perhaps it should've been `-l`. Anyway, it wasn't a very good approach to start with, so I'm fine with it not working.